# Keep all values intact when changing Activity

Tags: java, android-activity, android-tabs

[image]

When I enter anything under **Current Trip** tab and switch to the **Display Result** tab and come back to the **Current Trip** tab, all the entries goes back to default. How do I prevent it?

I would like anything I enter or select under **Current Trip** to stay intact even if I go to the **Display Result** tab view.

I am using one MainActivity which has two separate activities for each tab.

This is what's inside one of the Tab fragment:

```
package com.test.testing;


public class Trip2 extends Fragment {
     EditText nameOfInf;    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        final RelativeLayout mFrame2 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.trip, container, false ); 

        final Button btnCalc = (Button) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        nameOfInf = (EditText) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText tollAmount = (EditText) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.etToll);

        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        });
        return mFrame2;
    }
```

}

I want to save the value of:

```
nameOfInf = (EditText) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.etName);
```

So if I switch to another tab this will be saved and upon returning back to the tab the value will stay intact.

How do I implement the following if it will work:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putString("name", nameOfInf.getText());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  nameOfInf.setText (savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save state in a bundle when the activity is paused, and restore that data when the activity is resumed. Read up on the [Android activity lifecycle.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

This assumes you are embedding activities, in a tab control.

Comment: Would i Use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` method in MainActivity? or inside each Tab Fragment activity? I am calling the buttons and the textboxes inside it's own activity.

Comment: It is giving me an error. I will update my question with what I have

Comment: Can I also use SharedPreference?

Comment: I made it a Global Variable so I can access it outside the onCreateClass method