# Lost all values from new activity - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a MainActivity and SecondActivity. In the MainActivity, there is a button called "btnInformation" that navigates to the SecondActivity. For the SecondActivity, there are some textviews, which is used for entering values and a back button(btnBackToMain) which is used to go back to the MainActivity and the problem is that, after I entered some values in the SecondActivity then back to the MainActivity, then when I click on the btnInformation again, all the values in SecondActivity is gone.

I think I have similar problem to this guy [Keep all values intact when changing Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955468/keep-all-values-intact-when-changing-activity?answertab=active#tab-top). But, I'm not very sure about it. If yes, then I have to do the save-state and restore-state in SecondActivity, am I right?

Here are my codes:

MainActivity:

```
    btnInformation.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

SecondActivity:

```
    btnBackToMain.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: you should use finish() not startActivity

Comment: If you save your values in an app-wide class, such a s an `AndroidViewModel` (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) your data should persist

Answer (score 2):

You should use finish() method as like back button

```
btnBackToMain.setOnClickListener {
    finish()
}
```

If you use startActivity , it does not come back old activity and opens a new activity.

```
MainActivity -> SecondActivity -> MainActivity
                                  <-finish()
                  old values
```

Comment: Hi Kasim, thanks for your replied. I just tried it and still not working.It seems to me, everytime when I click on the btnInformation, it just start another new activity instead of go back to the SecondActivity with all the values.

Comment: I edited my answer. When you use startActivity you open a new activity. This activity is not your old MainActivity. If you want to see it on all screens, you have to move the values